# How. Filming inside a landscape?

Tags: animation

I know how to animate a little figure. with a back screen. but how do prof animate in a little map, with trees. 
Will try to make a little car. moving around in a landscape. but at the same time I will like to control my wheels in there.
Can't find the right set of words. to find tutorials on Filming or animation inside a landscape.
can you help me find som link on tutorials for that?

or tips to programs used for the animation recording part?

Thanks and peace :-)

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking. "or tips to programs used for the animation recording part" sounds like motion capture, "Will try to make a little car" sounds like modeling, "animation inside a landscape" sounds like animation and camera tracking, and "tutorials" seems like you want links.

Comment: EXAMPEL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QIN3GGAPSA

This animation are recordet in a 3D. do any know what program is used for retording, setting up camera. and at the same time the animals are animated to walk and talk.

Comment: Please try to make focused questions on specific issues. What you are asking is not possible to answer in a single post. Long complicated tutorials are discouraged here. To understand how to make better use of this site please take the [tour] and read through the [help] section. Particularly [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) Broad questions with many steps asking how to go from beginner to master blender are not well suited for this site.

Answer (score 1):

You are also starting out on a new adventure, and a very steep learning curve. If you don't already have it, you will need to gain an understanding of modelling, texturing, rigging, lighting, staging, sound/sound fx, pacing, composing, compositing, story structure, cinematic structure, and, and, and. Blender can do many things, and you have a lot to learn just for that. But consider you will also have to gain some mastery of other programs like audacity (for audio) and the gimp (for texturing/backgrounds) as well before you can, as you say it, prof animate in a little map.

I guess you need to do what every one of us has done, search for tutorials on what you need to know at the time. Why not start with the opening shot on your example there. [Model a rock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gs5nBoIxnOg), [some trees](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQUO9yL2vYQ), [flowers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gF6qkByl-_M), and a little character like you already have. Then [light your scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGUAn-Zh8cQ) and set up the [animated camera shot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-44yRfQ-A0). All of these links are to tutorials I found with a single search, all leading to dozens of others that may fit your needs more.

I was going to suggest that you also try to track down the production files for [Big Buck Bunny](https://peach.blender.org/) and study the blend files because that movie opens similarly to your example. But it seems that more and more of Blender is getting locked up behind paywalls. Even so, there are many good blend files still freely available that you can download, open up and study.

I hope I haven't put you off. But I think it will help you more to understand that you will never get to where you want to be (prof animate) by starting with a single animation and then asking SO how to do everything else.

Comment: Thanks for take your time to answer my question.

I will try to folow all your link. yes Im new to animation. but what im trying. it to know what software to put my focus on. so I one day in the future did folow the right road to reach my goal.

My road....

1. Make objekt in 3d (I know that now)
2. I also know how to animate it on the sceen in blender.

What Im looking for is, the best program to learn about to reach my goal. 

Again thank you so much. and sorry my english